# WCF MessageBodyMember Required

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to WCF and have a basic question about the `[MessageBodyMember]` attribute.

As far as I understand, in the case of the `[DataMember]` attribute, unless you set IsRequired=true there will not be a problem getting and deserializing the message.

What will happen if you send a message that is missing `MessageBodyMember`s? (From an earlier version of the interface, for example)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a [`MessageBodyMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagebodymemberattribute.aspx) defined where you're explicitly defining the message contract with a [`MessageContractAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagecontractattribute.aspx), the message will still be processed to the best of it's ability.

From the MSDN documentation ["Using Message Contracts"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx) (under the "Message Contract Versioning" section, emphasis mine):

> Message bodies have similar versioning rules—both **missing** and
>   additional message body parts are ignored.

Of course, if your contract (or implementation) isn't constructed to handle a missing part of the body, then that's a separate issue altogether.